# Why my Alfresco is so slow

Tags: tomcat7, alfresco

### Situation

I have an alfresco community 4.2.f installation in production.

It is running on a `x86_64` machine with linux `RHEL 6.6`. The machine has 16Gb of RAM, and 12 cores.

Alfresco uses `Java 64-bit 1.7.0_25-b15` and `Tomcat 7.0.52`.

### Problem

Alfresco becomes very slow every two or three days. There isn't any apparent reason.

I've seen logs and tomcat accepts requests but freezes for seconds and then continues to function normally. Process/Commit time is about 15ms although the response really took about 10 seconds.

Looking `jstack -F prc_id` I get this:

```
Thread 27669: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=226 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=68, line=2082 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=62, line=467 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=3, line=86 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=3, line=32 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=141, line=1068 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1130 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=724 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 27668: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=226 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=68, line=2082 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=62, line=467 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=3, line=86 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=3, line=32 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=141, line=1068 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1130 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=724 (Interpreted frame)
```

There are very much threads `BLOCKED` and they are related to `org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.poll` class.

I think the problem is related to Tomcat itself, but I don't know why.

### Question

What could be the problem?

### Actualization (jvm parameter and db data, 2015-03-17)

#### Java

The java process is:

```
/opt/alfresco-4.2.f/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/alfresco-4.2.f/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms6g -Xmx11g -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -server -Dalfresco.home=/opt/alfresco-4.2.f -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=palfresco.dipalme.org -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/alfresco-4.2.f/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /opt/alfresco-4.2.f/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/alfresco-4.2.f/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/alfresco-4.2.f/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/alfresco-4.2.f/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/alfresco-4.2.f/tomcat/temp
```

Java paraters:

```
-Xms6g
-Xmx11g
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:+UseParallelOldGC
-server
```

#### Database

The database is PostgresSQL 9.1 in a Debian IBM LPAR Power7 machine with 2Gb of RAM an 2 CPU.

It isn't using swap space and it hasn't any significant load.

Comment: Did you try following the Alfresco performance tuning documentation? eg [JVM tuning for Alfresco](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/jvm-tuning.html)

Comment: Yes, although I didn't put it in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better inspect the root cause of these locks examining the thread dumps deeper in order to find out if there's some library causing this issue.

In my experience I saw that another cause could be a massive Garbage collection, which can be resolved with a -Xmx increase.

What's the average load on your machine? Which DB are you using? Which JVM settings do you have?

Moreover I can point you to this very good post about [Troubleshooting Tomcat](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2013/03/28/hanging-thread%E2%80%943-steps-troubleshooting-tomcat)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I've seen db locks and haven't been anyone, although Alfresco was very slow again. I put db data and jvm parameter in the original mesage.